# Why is Zend Framework (Zend_Db_table) rejecting this SQL Query?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I'm working on a simple `JOIN` of two tables (`urls` and `companies`). I am using this query call:

```
print $this->_db->select()->from(array('u' => 'urls'),
                                 array('id', 'url', 'company_id'))
                          ->join(array('c' => 'companies'),
                                 'u.company_id = c.id');
```

which is out putting this query:

```
SELECT `u`.`id`, `u`.`url`, `u`.`company_id`, `c`.* FROM `urls` AS `u` INNER JOIN `companies` AS `c` ON u.company_id = c.id
```

Now, I'd prefer the `c.*` to not actually appear, but either way it doesn't matter. ZF dies with this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1"
```

but I can run that query perfectly fine in my MySQL CLI. Any ideas how to fix up this query?

Comment: Check if you have a reserved keyword (field) in the companies table.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just tried that code in a test script against ZF 1.10 and MySQL 5.1, and it works fine.

What user/password are you using to connect to your database?  It says "or access violation" so I would test that your db username has the right privileges.  Try connecting in the MySQL CLI using the *exact* same user/password and connection method (because privileges can vary depending on the client host, even for the same user/password).

See [MySQL Zend Framework - SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204571/mysql-zend-framework-sqlstate42000-syntax-error-or-access-violation-1064)

Btw, you can omit `c.*` columns by passing an empty array for columns as the third argument to `join()`:

```
->join(array('c' => 'companies'), 'u.company_id = c.id', array());
```